# C# Windows RT Listbox Horizontal Scroll Issue

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have the following listbox control placed inside a grid, but the listbox does not scroll horizontally properly. If you drag the scrollbar over it works fine, but if you click on the arrows it only scrolls half way through. How can I fix this behaviour?

```
<Page
x:Class="App5.MainPage"
IsTabStop="false"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App5"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
      <ListBox Height="400" Width="200" 
       ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto">
      <ListBoxItem Content="This is my horizontal test # 1" />
      <ListBoxItem Content="This is my second horizontal test which spams across" />
      </ListBox>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any items on your ListBox?

Comment: Yes, I programatically add items to the listbox. The scrolling works fine if I drag the scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug in WinRT to me. You can still click on the HorizontalLargeIncrease RepeatButton and that works. Perhaps you could edit the template of the ListBox/ScrollViewer/ScrollBar/HorizontalLargeIncrease RepeatButton to extend its click/touch target to overlap the area of the HorizontalSmallIncrease RepeatButton, so regardless of where you click - it will still scroll completely.

Alternatively you can set ListBox.ItemsPanel/ItemsPanelTemplate to a StackPanel. Note that the default is a VirtualizingStackPanel which is better for long lists since it will not generate all the items in the bound collection as opposed to the StackPanel, but it seems like the issue you see is with the VirtualizingStackPanel.

Comment: Asked about the bug on MSDN forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/33415918-dfa2-46da-9b7f-65fcc2114042

Comment: Thanks Fillip. I also noticed that wrapping the ListBox control with a ScrollViewer control seemed to work as well.